# View with entityreference: make exposed filter autocomplete

Tags: views, entities, ajax

I have two content types A and B. B has an entity reference to A. 
When creating a view to list all nodes from type A, I want to use some exposed filters. One filter would be to give all nodes from type A that have a reference to a certain node of type B. 
The exposed filter I get is a textfield that needs a nid. I made it autocomplete (via form_alter), but now the value that gets saved is "node title (nid)".

Anyone having the same problem, and knows how to fix it?

EDIT:
I found this patch for entity_reference, but it doesn't seem to work.
http://drupal.org/node/1492260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch I added to the initial question did the trick: http://drupal.org/node/1492260
The only thing you need to know is that you need to enable a checkbox on the fieldsettings of the field on you content type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validate handler, that pulls out of the nid from the autocompleted text - most use a text like `title [nid]` or similar. Then set that as the submitted values which View then would use. You need to make sure your validate handler acts first in order for this to work.

Comment: I'm using this for #element_validate: _entityreference_autocomplete_tags_validate But it's not working. The id doesn't get filled in in the query.