# How to get a field in a exposed filter criteria as an autocomplete?

Tags: 7, views, entities, ajax

In a view the field which has widget autocomplete does not get
an option to select as dropdown or autocomplete in exposed filter criteria.
I have a field in a content type which has following properties.
Type : **entity reference**
widget : **autocomplete**
How can I set a exposed filter criteria field as autocomplete ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Views Autocomplete Filter](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) for getting autocomplete exposed filter in views. Module page says :

```
Add autocomplete functionality to the views filter text fields.

 - It works for node titles or cck text fields.
 - The autocomplete results are actually the view results, so they are view related.
```

But the field which you will expose & use autocomplete should be in the views result fields as well.

Comment: oh, this is a nice hackey work-around :). +1 for I suppose a non patch approach to the problem! ymmv if you dont like extra modules for things.

Comment: can u please help me out by chat in getting this functionality

Comment: @harshal I am available on IRC with nickname RajeevK

Comment: is it #drupal-support

Comment: I cant see you on irc pls provide me some way to chat or some link

Answer (score 1):

This drupal.stackexchange post shows that a current patch that needs review and is slated for 1.0 release adds this functionality to Views:

[View with entityreference: make exposed filter autocomplete](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38713/view-with-entityreference-make-exposed-filter-autocomplete)

The related issue queue request is here:

https://drupal.org/node/1492260

The answer to your question is to apply the patch found in the issue queue. If you dont know how to do that -- now is a great time to learn something new about patch files, Linux, DrushMake or Git.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, apply the patch from [Generalize TaxonomyIndexTid filter to be available for all entity reference fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2429699).